# Eureka registers only one instance of application

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, load-balancing, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I configured Eureka clients and Eureka server, and when I run two instances of the same service on ports 8000 and 8001 locally through IntelliJ, they are registered on Eureka, but when I try to do it through docker-compose, it registers only one instance on one port.

This is the part where i configure the ports in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  currency-exchange-service:
    image: ...
    mem_limit: 1000m
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "8001:8000"
    networks:
      - microservices-network
    depends_on:
      - service-registry
    environment:
      EUREKA.CLIENT.SERVICEURL.DEFAULTZONE: http://service-registry:8761/eureka
      MANAGEMENT.ZIPKIN.TRACING.ENDPOINT: http://zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans
```

Is this the wrong way to run the same service on two ports with docker-compose?

This is the application.properties file of the service

```
spring.application.name=currency-exchange-service
server.port=8000

#service-registry url
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

And this is the single instance registered on Eureka:

[image]

To mention again, this works when I run the service through IntelliJ on two different ports.

I tried setting the ports property as:

```
- ports:
    - "8000-8001:8000"
```

and running it with `docker-compose up --scale currency-exchange-service=2` , but didn't work.

Is this something I need to fix in the docker-compose.yml or in the configuration?

Comment: the instanceId uses the port, since they use the same port the instanceId is the same. `eureka.instance.instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.int}` or use some other available env var provided by docker.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But all i get now is _UP (1) - currency-exchange-service:-95576615_ on eureka for this service, one instance with random instance id is up